# SQL Server : Nested Select Query

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have a SQL query returning results based on a where clause.

I would like to include some more results, from the same table, dependent on what is found in the first select.

My select returns rows with ID's that meet the where criteria. It does happen that the table has more rows with this ID, but that does not meet the initial where criteria. Rather than re querying the DB with a separate call, I would like to use one select statement to also get these extra rows with the same ID. ID is not the index/ID. Its a naming convention I am using here.

Pseudo: (two steps)

```
1: select * from table where condition=xxx

2: for each row returned, (select * from table where id=row.id)
```

I want to do:

```
select 
    id as thisID, field1, field2, 
    (select id, field1, field2 from table where id = thisID) 
from 
    table 
where 
    condition=xxx
```

I have multiple joins in my real query, and just cant get the above to work. I unfortunately can not supply the real query, but I get an error of:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. Invalid column name 'thisID'

My query works fine with the multiple joins, without the above. I am trying to retrieve these extra records as part of the current working query.

Example:

**TABLE**

```
select * from table where col3 = 'green'

id,   col1,  col2, col3

123 | blue | red | green
-------------------------
567 | blue | red | green
-------------------------
123 | blue | red | blue
-------------------------
890 | blue | red | green
-------------------------
```

I want to return all 4 rows, because although `row 3` fails the where condition, it has the same `col1` value as `row 1` (123), and I need to include it, as it is part of a "set" that I need to locate / import, called / referenced by `id=123`.

What I am doing manually now, is getting row one, and then running another query based on row 1's ID, to get row 3 as well.

Comment: ... well, can you give us sample data layouts?  Do you have a per-row unique id (ids aren't required to be unique?  Should the matching rows show up from the subquery also?  What happens if multiple rows with the same key - should they be reported by the subquery, but listed with a different row (different unique id)?  For best results, please post as complete a query as possible (anonymize if you need to).

Comment: Hi @Clockwork-Muse, the query has 5 joins and many, many fields... I am "importing" data from an old system as take-on to a new system we are developing. I will add some more detail. For the moment, I have gone ahead and just re-queried every initial row, as I need to make some headway, but I would love to get the above working for future reference.

Comment: That's fine, but unless you tell us what you expect the data to look like when you're done (in regards to general values copied), we can't sensibly help you.  Heck, _you_ might be surprised by the results...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse , I added an example

Comment: And the other situations I mentioned?  What happens if there's another copy of id 123 with green?  And is your result set just a copy of the rows (4 columns wide), or do you want the 'matching row' columns first, then the non-matching ones (for a row with 8 columns)?

Comment: CORRECTION: @Clockwork-Muse , its all the same thing, I want the rows returned as if all of them met the where clause. 123 blue, should get added / returned with all the other rows. No order, I basically want to "simulate" row 3 as being "green", along with row 1. P.S. Row 3 should retain its unique fields, Ie, blue, but I want the row (3) returned as "if" it was indeed a green row, when looking for 123, green.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Where IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

```
select id as thisID, field1, field2 from table
where id in
 (select id from table where condition=xxx)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to match the output the OP wants - he's looking to show the matching criteria for every row.

Comment: I think it does.. The OP 'seem' to want all the info of all the IDs that is part of the 'Green' category

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Let say you table is below and called #Temp

```
Id  Col1    Col2    Col3
123 blue    red     green
567 blue    red     green
123 blue    red     blue
890 blue    red     green
```

Will get the `id` to a temp table

```
Create Table #T1(Id int)
Insert Into #T1
Select Id
From #Temp
Where Col3='green'
```

Then

```
Select distinct *
From #Temp
Where Id in (select Id from #T1) Or Col3='Green'
```

Which result all the rows from main table

**Update**

If you want to use the way you currently using, try something like below

```
select 
    id as thisID, field1, field2, 
    (select top 1 id from table where id = t.id) as Id,
    (select top 1 field1 from table where id = t.id) as field1,
    (select top 1 field2 from table where id = t.id) as field2,
from 
    table t
where 
    condition=xxx
```

Comment: As mentioned, I need it all in one query, as part of a bigger join. I don;t think the temp table creation will work here, as that's basically what I am doing now manually, in code.

Comment: I would have to create a temp table for for every single original record returned, inline, to get the rest. This query runs on a table of thousands of records. Not sure if that's even possible?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder: You can't select multiple columns as a field in a subqurey!!

Comment: So I've learned :-) Does not solve my problem tho... can what I want, be done with one query?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder: Not quite sure.. I have updated the answer. Please try